# Cannot open database requested by the login

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I read the book of Freeman MVC. When I put "add-migration initial" on nuget console:

```
`An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Cannot open database "SportsStore" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-3IVHO1V\myname'.
```

This problem, as I understand it, appears due to the fact that there is no table with such a name. For example, if you remove the name of SportsStore, then everything is OK (almost). So how to make everything work, that is, create a table.

My connection string:

```
Server=(localDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

And startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SportsStore.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SportsStore
{

    public class Startup
    {
        IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                            options.UseSqlServer(
                                Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));

            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "pagination",
                    template: "Products/Page{page}",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" });
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had this problem before, but not in EF Core. Solved it by loading the connection string into a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx, modifying it (switch the db to master), logging in, creating the base db, then rolling code as normal.  Dunno if Core has an equivalent class. If not, you'd have to parse it yourself. It's not too bad.